# Eclipse Python Integration

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I found this [python plugin list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EclipsePythonIntegration) but thought I'd ask if anyone has any experience with anything listed there?

I'm totally new to both python and dynamic programming languages if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5):

PyDev is the most widely used IDE I think. I'm using it not very often, but if I do, it suits me quite well.

Answer (score 2):

[PyDev](http://pydev.org/) is the best I've used.  I use it every day.  When they had a pay version I paid for it.  I use it on my Mac and Linux box and love it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [PyDev](http://pydev.org/). It's come a long way since I started using it.  That might be it's greatest strength, it's very actively developed.  It's got good support for Django and a whole list of other worthwhile features.  If you're an Eclipse user you should definitely try it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to Eclipse, it's probably best to go with the DLTK. As a bonus, you get support for a number of other languages (Tcl, Ruby, Javascript) too.

Answer (score 1):

Pydev supports python including vs 3.1, jython and ironpython. It is said that ironpython support in pydev is one of the best availables.

So pydev is probably the best plugin for eclipse. Some few months ago pydev and pydev extensions, the non-free part of pydev, were merged and released free. This is not related with abandonware, contrarily pydev is being actively developped.

Last release added support for Django (and there was also support for google application engine).